# How Can I enable Ubuntu One indicator?

Tags: ubuntu-one, indicator

How Can I enable Ubuntu One indicator in 12.10?

I installed the package :  indicator-sync
but in vain. Rebooting the computer does not help.

---

Command : `aptitude search ubuntuone`

```
p   desktopcouch-ubuntuone                                                    - Ubuntu One connection extension for Desktop CouchDB                                 
i   gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0                                                    - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
p   gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0:i386                                               - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
i   libubuntuoneui-3.0-1                                                      - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
p   libubuntuoneui-3.0-1:i386                                                 - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
p   libubuntuoneui-dev                                                        - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
p   libubuntuoneui-dev:i386                                                   - Ubuntu One widget library                                                           
i   python-ubuntuone-client                                                   - Ubuntu One client Python libraries                                                  
i   python-ubuntuone-control-panel                                            - Ubuntu One Control Panel - Python Libraries                                         
p   python-ubuntuone-devtools                                                 - Ubuntu One development tools - Python modules                                       
i   python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol                                          - Python library for Ubuntu One file storage and sharing service                      
v   python2.7-ubuntuone-client                                                -                                                                                     
v   python2.7-ubuntuone-storageprotocol                                       -                                                                                     
i   rhythmbox-ubuntuone                                                       - Ubuntu One Rhythmbox plugin                                                         
i   ubuntuone-client                                                          - Ubuntu One client                                                                   
i   ubuntuone-client-gnome                                                    - Ubuntu One client GNOME integration                                                 
p   ubuntuone-client-gnome:i386                                               - Ubuntu One client GNOME integration                                                 
p   ubuntuone-client-proxy                                                    - Ubuntu One client Proxy support                                                     
i   ubuntuone-control-panel                                                   - Ubuntu One Control Panel                                                            
v   ubuntuone-control-panel-gui                                               -                                                                                     
i   ubuntuone-control-panel-qt                                                - Ubuntu One Control Panel - Qt frontend                                              
i   ubuntuone-couch                                                           - Ubuntu One CouchDB                                                                  
p   ubuntuone-dev-tools                                                       - Ubuntu One development tools                                                        
p   ubuntuone-file-storage-api                                                - Ubuntu One File Storage APIs
```

---

When I log in to my session, the indicator-sync-service is well running. Yet there is no icon in top panel.

[image: indicator-sync-service]

Sync and upload notifications appear normally and Ubuntu one client is functioning correctly. I have several other indicators in my panel but I don't see any probability that one of them is conflicting with ubuntu one indicator.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5CBu.png):

Comment: did you install the package ubuntuone-client as well?
it does not show up until ubuntuone is installed in general.

Comment: Sure! I am using Ubuntu one client since Beta 1. See Edited question. but no indicator at all. However, I get notifications when sync starts or when files get uploaded to cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to install the `indicator-sync` package as well. You may need to log out and back in after doing so, for the icon to appear in the top panel.

If you have not set up Ubuntu One yet, though, it will not appear. You will need to configure Ubuntu One to connect, and then the icon should appear after the client starts. It may take some time after you log in for it to appear, as the client is configured on a delayed start to avoid slowing down log-in.

The `gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1` package is also required to be installed for the functionality to work. It is installed by default on Ubuntu 12.10, but is only recommended by `ubuntuone-client` so that it may be uninstalled by users who do not want the indicator. If you've managed to uninstall this package, you will need to re-install it, and then restart the Ubuntu One client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yet, indicator-sync is already installed, and my Ubuntu one client is already configured. reconfiguring it does not help neither!

Comment: Is indicator-sync getting started when you log in? Is it running? Does it crash?

Comment: yes, the indicator-sync-service gets started when I log in. No crash at all.

Comment: Is gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1 installed? It's installed by default, but maybe you did something to remove it? Other than that, I'd suggest checking the logs. Maybe you're hitting a bug somewhere.

Comment: Indeed. You got it @dobey .   That package was not installed and it appears that it was not installed by default. I have just checked the logs. Anyway. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but rather an alternative. You can also install the app called "[Ubuntu One Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-ubuntuone)".

Type the following commands in the terminal to do so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
```

Comment: Thanks. My issue is solved thanks to @dobey
I have been using the indicator-ubuntuone in 12.04 Precise Pangolin. Has the developer added support for Quantal?

Comment: As of today, the PPA doesn't work for 12.10 yet. But if you upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, the app should still work.

Comment: It'a fresh install. I am using indicator-ubuntuone in my 12.04 partition and I am loving it.

Answer (score 2):

From terminal, type:

```
ubuntuone-installer
```

The above command aims to installer Ubuntu One Service. After finishing, you type your ubuntu one account to synchronize your files with server.

Comment: I have met the same problem when I tried connecting my musics from UbuntuOne in Rhythmbox. I succeeded to access my collections of music after installing Ubuntu One service like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 13.04, you can add following command to startup applications:

/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon

Solution:

1. Open Startup Applications
2. Click Add
3. Enter Name: Ubuntu One, Command: /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon, Comment: Ubuntu One
4. Click Save
5. Close Startup Applications, Logout and Login
6. You should see cloudy indicator in the right corner :)

Comment: it doesnt work for me.